# Remove rows violating column datatype

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe from which I have to remove row violating the datatype of the column:

```
            ts       a         b         c      d
0   1555338562    9.01      True   1648.37   1.01
1   1555338563    9.01     1.022   1648.37   1.01
2   1555338564    9.01     1.022   AVC       1.01
3   1555338565    9.01     1.022   1648.37   1.01
4   1555338566    9.01     1.022   1648.33   1.01
5   1555338567    test     1.022   1648.33   1.01
```

Datatype of Columns:

```
data_types = { "ts": "int64", 
               "a": "float64", 
               "b": "float64", 
               "c": "float64", 
               "d": "float64"
             }
```

In above example, rows 0, 2, and 5 will be removed as they violate datatype for columns b, c and a respectively. The expected output is:

```
            ts       a         b         c      d
0   1555338563    9.01     1.022   1648.37   1.01
1   1555338565    9.01     1.022   1648.37   1.01
2   1555338566    9.01     1.022   1648.33   1.01
```

Any suggestion how can I achieve this using pandas?

EDIT:
We can have string or boolean column as well in future. For example,

```
            ts       a         b         c      d    e       f
0   1555338562    9.01      True   1648.37   1.01 True  Test_1
1   1555338563    9.01     1.022   1648.37   1.01 True  Test_2
2   1555338564    9.01     1.022   AVC       1.01 True  Test_2
3   1555338565    9.01     1.022   1648.37   1.01 True  Test_2
4   1555338566    9.01     1.022   1648.33   1.01 True  Test_2
5   1555338567    test     1.022   1648.33   1.01 False Test_2
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but Pandas already assigns these columns to a higher-level datatype (in this case text), so all a and c column values are treated as text, right?

Comment: @Ch3steR - this example yes, but the OP's example will have a and c dtypes as "object", so he will not be able to know which value causes it

Comment: @Ch3steR Columns can have any datatype. For eg, a new column 'e' can be added in future with str or bool datatype.

Comment: @Ch3steR It will be around 20,000 rows max.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using *Pandas > 1.0*, try using [`DataFrame.convert_dytpes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html), then use [`Dataframe.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to convert all columns to either `int` or `float`, Something like this might work:

```
In [1118]: for i in df.columns:
      ...:     df[i] = pd.to_numeric(df[i], errors='coerce')
      ...:

In [1122]: df = df.dropna()

In [1123]: df
Out[1123]: 
           ts     a      b        c     d
1  1555338563  9.01  1.022  1648.37  1.01
3  1555338565  9.01  1.022  1648.37  1.01
4  1555338566  9.01  1.022  1648.33  1.01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom function for this which put `True` where there correct type else `False` using [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) now you can use this as *boolean mask*, then use [`df.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) then use [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html). About [`Data type objects`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

```
data_types = { "ts": "int64", 
               "a": "float64", 
               "b": "float64", 
               "c": "float64", 
               "d": "float64"
             }
cast_mapping = { 'int64': np.int64, 
                 'float64': np.float64, 
                 'bool': np.bool_, 
                 'str': np.str_
               }

def change_type(s):
    cast_to = s.name
    def cast_type(val):
        try:
            cast_mapping[cast_to](val)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return s.map(cast_type)

df[df.apply(change_type)].dropna().astype(data_types)

           ts     a      b        c     d
1  1555338563  9.01  1.022  1648.37  1.01
3  1555338565  9.01  1.022  1648.37  1.01
4  1555338566  9.01  1.022  1648.33  1.01
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ch3steR's answer worked perfectly fine for int, float, and string datatypes but failed with boolean as Python internally convert boolean to integer. Following method works for all datatypes:

```
data_types = { "ts": "int64", 
           "a": "float64", 
           "b": "float64", 
           "c": "float64", 
           "d": "float64"
         }
cast_mapping = { 'int64': int, 
             'float64': float, 
             'bool': bool, 
             'str': str
           }

def change_type(s):
    cast_to = s.name
    def cast_type(val):
        return isinstance(val, cast_mapping[cast_to])
return s.map(cast_type)

df[df.apply(change_type)].dropna().astype(data_types)

           ts     a      b        c     d
1  1555338563  9.01  1.022  1648.37  1.01
3  1555338565  9.01  1.022  1648.37  1.01
4  1555338566  9.01  1.022  1648.33  1.01
```